# Rails update user status after 3 days - cron job alternative

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app user can be blocked if failed the Legal Test - which means that the user model will change its status from active to inactive `user.status = 'inactive'`. The business requirement is to return the status to active after 3 days.

I know I could use cron job like below:

```
every 1.day, :at => '12:00 am' do
  User.where(status_updated_at: Date.today <= 3.days.ago)
        .update_all(status: 'active')
end
```

But instead of searching the whole User db maybe there is another, better way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using sidekiq, resque, delayed_job ? A solution would be to schedule a job after 3 days specifically for that user to make it active again. I am using https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler for that.

Comment: This is not yet specified but probably I'm gonna use delayed_job. Ok I'll have 1k users this it will probably be the same as the cron job. I don't see the difference.

Comment: _"searching the whole User db"_ – how long does that query run?

Comment: @Stefan The app is at such an early stage that I can't say, but searching the database for just this is not a 'very scalable' solution

Comment: @mr_muscle I'd be surprised if the query takes more than a second, even for a large table (assuming an index on the field).

Comment: @Stefan Ok, but doesn't this seem like an outdated solution to you? I have mixed feelings

Comment: Using cron seems like a _simple_ solution to me. Easy to set up, easy to debug. I would probably move the actual code into a rake task in case I have to run it manually for some reason, i.e. `every :day, at: '12am' { rake 'users:reactivate' }`. And I wouldn't bother too much about a ~1s task that runs once a day :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to schedule a job, you can do this when you need to (i.e. the user actually tries to sign in) with an `after_initialize`

```
class User

  after_initialize :reinstate_if_ready

  def reinstate_if_ready
    self.status = 'active' if status_updated_at.nil? || status_updated_at <= 3.days.ago)
  end
```

end

Comment: Ok but if the user doesn't logout it will still work?

Comment: Yes, because the user record is re-loaded on every browser submission.  So basically on every browser call it will load the users record and execute the after_iniitialize method.